# VSCode Eslint configuration for a two projects workspace

Tags: node.js, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a folder with two projects, a Nodejs backend and a Vuejs frontend. I want to open both projects at the same time, and being able to use eslint to check and format code in both.

The problem I'm having is that whenever a get the configuration sort of working for the vue project, the js files in the backend are not validated.

My main question is if it is possible at all to do this or not. I've already followed countless tutorials on getting eslint+prettier+airbnb plus all of the relevant plugins working. Else, if is it better to open two instances of VSCode, one for the backend and another for the frontend, each with its own configuration.

Thanks !!!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have installed the Vetur and Eslint VSCode extensions, in case this makes any difference.

Comment: you can set your environment in eslint by adding `/* eslint-env node */` to your files or creating separate `.eslintrc` files in each directory

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments

Answer (score 33):

Yes, you can get this working. You'll need to update your workspace settings.

https://medium.com/devityoself/monorepo-eslint-vscode-6f5982c8404d

> [From Visual Studio Code]:
>
> 1. CMD + Shift + P
> 2. Start to type Workspace settings
> 3. Search for ESlint extension and look for Working Directories and select **Edit in settings.json**.
> 4. Enter the paths that need ESlint enabled
>
> ```
> { "eslint.workingDirectories": ["mobile/iOS", "platform/web"] }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. Please, note the selection of `Workspace settings`, not the global ones, when looking for eslint config option

Comment: You need to provide the answer here instead of just a link. Links can sometimes point to a 404.

Comment: Another option is to use [{"mode": "auto"}]. It will auto-detect the workspace based on file location.

Answer (score 11):

For me, this was an issue with the VS Code ESLint extension when you have the  app in a subfolder from the root. To solve it, I created a .vscode folder in the root with a file settings.json and this contents

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./app", "./another-app"]
}
```

This only works this way if you're using the VS Code "workspace" where you've started with an empty workspace and added directories to the workspace, so it's not a directory itself.

If you've loaded the parent folder using `Code ~/parent-folder` with a lot of subfolders for projects, and then you've got two folders inside those folders, you'll need to create the `.vscode/settings.json` in your parent folder, but then add in the folder path to the start, so

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./subfolder/app", "./subfolder/another-app"]
}
```

Comment: If I may ask, where is your .eslintrc located?

Comment: Each project (subdirectory of the parent/root folder) has it's own eslint file. Ideally we'd have it at the root but not there yet. I'm not sure if that might introduce new issues.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are frustrated with eslint working in the terminal but not in vscode, and only sometimes, you may find it's when you're opening up a root directory filled with projects. To fix this, open up your vscode preferences JSON file, and add:

```json
"eslint.workingDirectories":  [{"mode": "auto"}]
```

Hopefully this will help you get back to writing code and waste less time fighting with tooling!