# Parsing error : Cannot find module 'next/babel'

Tags: next.js, babeljs

**Update 1:**
`Updated the latest working solution to @Jeevan Rupacha answer, please scroll below to check it out.`

I have been encountering this error on every single new Next.js project that I create. The page can be compiled without any problem, it just keeps on showing as error on the first line in every js file.

Parsing error: Cannot find module 'next/babel'
Require stack:

- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\bundle.js
- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\eslint-parser.js
- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules\eslint-config-next\parser.js
- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js
- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules@eslint\eslintrc\lib\index.js
- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js
- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\index.js
- D:\app\next_app\ratu-seo\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
- c:\Users\Admin.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.1.23\server\out\eslintServer.js

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc` file? And what version of Next.js are you on?

Comment: I can't find the `.babelrc` file. And im on Next.js v11.0.1. Is it normal that the babelrc file is missing? I generated the whole project with npx create-next-app

Comment: @mitchiri_neko Yes, next uses swc to compile.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

**Note**: **`You don't need to create extra .babelrc file`**

`In your NextJS Project you have this file , named` **.eslintrc.json**,
`In this file`

You have following code

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

`Replace it with`

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

**Note**: If you only replace with

```
{
   "extends": ["next/babel"]
}
```

The red error sign will go but the code won't compile and gives compile error.

Comment: Thx! and agreed, should be at the top. adding a .babelrc file will disable SWC in NextJS v12

Comment: why they have not made this the default?

Comment: You may need to restart ESLint server -> <cmd/ctrl + shift + p> then start typing Restart ESLint Server

Comment: Generates this error: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/babel-font-loader-conflict

Answer (score 478):

Create file called `.babelrc` in your root directory and add this code:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

And in `.eslintrc`, replace the existing code with:

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

Comment: as soon as I replace the eslintrc extends, its gone! Big thanks!

Comment: What are the possible side effects of this?

Comment: This really helped.

Comment: @SaralKarki Can you explain what this does?

Comment: @DonCarleone read this doc https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason I got the errors even on the initial install using create-next-app.  This fixes it!

Comment: I tried this but weirdly eslint just stopped working. Do you know any causes of this?

Comment: I ended up switching back to `"extends": ["next", "next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"],` and then used `ctrl + shift + p` to `ESLint: Restart ESLint Server`.

Comment: Where do you get this from? There is no such thing as an eslint `next/babel` configuration - maybe there was in the past? Are you confusing `babel` configuration with `eslint` configuration? If you find that this answer causes more problems than it solves, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837984/2228771) instead.

Comment: Also had to call "ESLint: Restart ESLint Server" afterwards, bet then it worked!

Comment: Sounds outdated answer since SWC is now the default. I have this issue in a v13 app, very weird

Comment: @EricBurel Same here. Any updates?

Comment: People need to know that creating a `.babelrc` [opts you out of using swc to transpile your code](https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#unsupported-features).  That means your builds will be slower and if you care about minimizing your pipeline minutes (saving money), then you should avoid doing this.

Comment: The custom `.babelrc` will cause another conflict if your code also uses `next/font` , see [the description at here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/babel-font-loader-conflict)

Answer (score 141):

I had this same problem - but only when I wasn't opening the project folder directly. It appears to be related to how ESLint needs to be configured for workspaces.

In addition, the currently accepted answer works for VSCode but breaks `npm run lint` for me.

TL;DR - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61619698/2415176) which points to [this blog](https://medium.com/devityoself/monorepo-eslint-vscode-6f5982c8404d). This fixed it for me.

### Some Details

For example, if I have:

```
~
|  -- some_folder
|     | -- project_1
|     | -- project_2
|     ...files relating to both projects...
```

I'll often just `cd ~/some_folder && code .`

But then I get the same error you're experiencing. However, if I `cd ~/some_folder/project_1 && code .` then everything works fine.

If that's the case for you as well, then what you need (as described in the links above) is to:

- Create a workspace config
- Specify folders where you need ESLint to run

You can do this easily from VSCode. The net result (following my example above) is a file named `~/some_folder/.vscode/settings.json` with contents

```json
{
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "./project_1",
        "./project_2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had a monorepository with two different eslint configs that influenced each other. By creating the workspace config as described above the issue was gone.

Comment: This answer is pretty important! It fixed for me the errors. Still, the esLint config was way not enough just using next core web vitals. I ended up with these for now:
`extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:import/errors', 'plugin:import/warnings', 'plugin:react/recommended', 'next/core-web-vitals','prettier' ],`

Comment: I had the same issue in my monorepo setup and I believe this is the actual root cause solution, thanks! We shouldn't need to add anything to .eslintrc, and we especially shouldn't need to add a .babelrc since Next.js includes next/babel preset in the app.

Comment: Had the same problem in a monorepo. Adding vscode `settings.json` fixed it; thanks for taking the time to share!

Comment: seemed to work for me

Answer (score 22):

For `Nextjs 12` add `prettier` in `.eslintrc.json` file inside your root folder.

```
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"]
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for me. Babel is not a dependency of my NextJS project, and this was a result of prettier extensions. Adding unneeded babel configs or eslint extensions referencing babel is a redherring.

Comment: I've tried disabling the prettier extension but it did not suffice, I had to apply this fix... Still a better answer than the other since Next.js doesn't use Babel as a default anymore.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the issue occurs when I code in VSCode and use `pnpm` as the package manager, I tried lots of methods in StackOverflow, and finally, I find out that it's the duty of the VSCode ESLint plugin.

So, to fix the problem without uninstalling the plugin, add the following configuration in the `.vscode/settings.json` and reload your editor.

```json
{
  "eslint.packageManager": "pnpm"
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this option is deprecated, the only working solution for me was disable the plugin and just leverage on the turborepo setup

Answer (score 14):

Using Next.js, TypeScript, and Tailwind CSS, I updated the *.eslintrc.json* file with:

```
{      
  "extends": ["next/babel", "next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

then `ctrl + shift + p` and search for `ESLint: Restart ESLint Server`.

Answer (score 13):

For me, it's work with editing this file in NextJS 13 in app version: `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel", "next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me by just adding `prettier` in `.eslintrc` file.

```
{
  "extends": ["next", "prettier"]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try updating the `.eslintrc.json` file to

```
{
  "extends": ["next", "prettier","next/core-web-vitals"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"]
}
```

Also install prettier plugin if you don't have it already

```
npm install eslint-plugin-prettier@latest --save-dev
```

Don't have to include `.babelrc` file as it will replace Nextjs SWC compiler
S

Comment: This did it for me!

Answer (score 7):

## My Problem

I found this error in a project with PNPM, ESLint, and Monorepo architecture using Turborepo.

## ⚠️ WARNING!

UPDATE 27-8-2023: I created a new turborepo project and encountered this problem again, I found out, that implementing this solution will silently disable the entire ESLint system.

Please be careful! I recommend not using this solution anymore!

## My Solution

add this into the ESLint config file:

```js
parserOptions: {
    babelOptions: {
      presets: [require.resolve('next/babel')],
    },
  },
```

Comment: This solved my issue as well, I have the same setup pnpm, turbo. Thanks for this!

Comment: This disabled linting in VSCode unless I installed Next.js to the project with the eslint config.

Comment: @DonovanDikaio I have updated the turbo examples with this fix, so anyone in the future shouldn't encounter this error.

Comment: I am having this problem in VSCode with the Turborepo with-tailwind example, despite the example including the above configuration -- but only within VSCode.

Comment: This worked like a charm in my pnpm monorepo after trying a lot of other stuff.

Comment: @Aycox consider vote up when it's good for you, to help other find this solution.

Comment: worked like a charm. how did yo arrived to the solution?

Comment: @elpddev Because I'm an active vercel open source contributor, It's normal to know what's happen behind in the background.

Comment: @ImBIOS thank you. I wanted to know why babeloptions works when the default parser is not babel. Ive looked in eslint docs but could not find a reference. All i understood that parseroptions are given as is to a custom parser if it defined.

Comment: I'm not debugging it further, but I guess it's because of just a resolution error. In a normal monolith project, it can find the next/babel inside root node_modules. But, in turborepo monorepo, it requires a workaround to find it. So, we just resolve this thing with this resolution override to tell where the next/babel is.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem - Close the IDE and reopen it with the project folder !!

Answer (score 3):

This is still an issue with NextJS 13.4.2. This is the best fix I've found:

```
{
  // You might want to additionally set this in monorepos where Next.js app is in a subdir
  "root": true,
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      // Adapt to your needs (e.g. some might want to only override "next.config.js")
      "files": ["*.js"],
      // This is the default parser of ESLint
      "parser": "espree",
      "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2020
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40687#issuecomment-1378845989): Issues tab from the NextJS repo on Github.

Comment: This works for me. Tried everything. I had to use

"files": ["*.js","*.mjs"]

because I'm working with modules.

Comment: I went with `files: ["*.js", "*.jsx", "*.[c|m]js"]` as the config was complaining when linting `.eslintrc.cjs`. I assumed it would be the same for all JS files, so added `.jsx` just in case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vscode and have multiple folders for your project create .vscode folder in the root of the project and create setting.json file and add following configuration.

```
 {
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
   "./client",
   "./server"
   ] 
 }
```

Make sure to include the right folder names of your projects

Comment: In my case, I have a vscode workspace. 

`
{
 "folders": [
  {
   "path": "."
  }
 ],
 "settings": {
    "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./server", "./admin"]
 }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

You can also always try updating React and then Next. I had the same error message then updated them both and now my app is working fine.

Upgrade React version to latest
Most applications already use the latest version of React, with Next.js 11 the minimum React version has been updated to 17.0.2.

To upgrade you can run the following command:

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Or using yarn:

```
yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Upgrade Next.js version to latest
To upgrade you can run the following command in the terminal:

```
npm install next@latest
```

or

```
yarn add next@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue with the Nextjs app and the following worked for me. I no longer have issue with next/babel and I can run yarn **lint**.

Add prettier to your project

```
yarn add --dev eslint-config-prettier
```

Update your eslint config as follows

```
{
  "extends": ["prettier", "next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

Add global vscode settings and include your project path

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./your-project"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this issues happens for installing eslint and next/core-web-vitals creates conflicts with the parser, just update the eslint config for parser.

```
  "parser": "espree",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  }
```

Alternatively update the config with

```
  "extends": ["next"],
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project builds fine but are only getting the ***Cannot find module 'next/babel' error*** in vscode on line 1 and your eslintrc file is not at the root level of your workspace then simply...

1. copy/cut and paste your eslintrc file to the root of your workspace
2. close vscode
3. reopen vscode

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to disable VSCode ESLint extension.

Unfortunately when I added **["next/babel"]** in extends, the **npm run lint** stopped working and Eslint in vscode did not underlining any abnormalities.

Comment: If you disable vs code eslint extension then it wouldn't underline abnormalities

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + shift + p

> TypeScript: Restart TS server

Answer (score 0):

Really, just adding `prettier` to `"extends": ["next/core-web-vitals]` to have something like ==> `{"extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"]}`, gets rid of the error, without having to create an extra **.babelrc** file. But another research that needs to be done, is to know, if there are any downsides to doing it, and ***i think the answer is NO***

Answer (score 0):

In my project, i just run `yarn add @babel/core` and run
`ctrl + shift + p` in vscode, excute `ESLint: Restart ESlint Server`

> ESLint: Restart ESlint Server

it works, and `npm run lint` works fine too.

```
> Executing task: yarn run lint <

✔ No ESLint warnings or errors
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is that I added `"eslint.packageManager": "yarn"` to the `setting.json` of VSCode before, and I tried to use the same setup within a new project managed with `pnpm`. After adding   `"eslint.packageManager": "pnpm"` for the new workspace, and reload window, than the issue's gone.

I've tried adding `"extends": ["next/babel", "next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"]` to `.eslintrc.js`, it will fix the error only within VSCode, but will cause the other error when building my Next.js app.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting we have answers for two separate issues here:

- OP's issue was with Nextjs 11 where the solution was adding to the eslint config

  - It's hard to say what OP's root cause was without knowing if it was a monorepo, but adding a .babelrc was certainly not the solution since Next.js [includes the next/babel preset in the app](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/babel#:%7E:text=Next.js%20includes,to%20your%20app) by default. It may have been related to Prettier since Next.js has some suggestions about [using it with eslint](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/eslint#prettier). Adding "prettier" to my `extends` did make the error go away on my end, but that wasn't the root cause in my case.
- Others including me ran into the same message with Nextjs 13, this time in a monorepo setup.

  - The root cause solution was as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68838570/8183576) once I set `eslint.workingDirectories` with each of my packages the error went away for good

Answer (score 0):

### My Working Solution: uninstal vscode-eslint plugin

after longs and painfully hours struggling with this issue, trying every suggested *working* solution I found the only real one: remove the eslint plugin from vscode and just leverage on the turborepo configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `next` in `eslint-config-custom`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `next` in `eslint-config-custom` to make `next/babel` available