# Parsing error: Cannot find module 'next/babel'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs

I've just created a new nextjs app by runnning the command "npx create-next-app". After launching my server with "yarn dev" , i got this issue like described below:

```
reservations\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\eslint-parser.js
```

- C:\my-reservations\frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-next\parser.js
- C:\my-reservations\frontend\node_modules@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js
- C:\my-reservations\frontend\node_modules@eslint\eslintrc\lib\index.js
- C:\my-reservations\frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js
- C:\my-reservations\frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\index.js
- C:\my-reservations\frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
- c:\Users\adan1.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.1.23\server\out\eslintServer.jseslint

how can i fix that?

Comment: Today i create a next app using `npm` and i did't got any error!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163385/parsing-error-cannot-find-module-next-babel

Answer (score 1):

Try running `yarn add babel-eslint -D` in your terminal.