# Parsing error: Cannot find module 'next/babel' in my Next.js app

Tags: next.js, eslint, eslintrc, babel-eslint

I know there are a lot of answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68193974/8684521), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68548622/8684521) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837984/8684521) out there and some people may flag my question as duplicate, but believe me I am struggling with this because neither of them is working for me now. Those were working before but looks like the solution is depreciated or expired.

I have no idea about eslint whatsoever, the only thing I like about eslint is that it underlines the unimported/undeclared variables with red line, that's why I installed eslint extension in my VS Code editor.

Also, I am not opening the code directory directly in my VS Code, I have other projects too in the same workspace, e.g. I have a structure like this:

```
|  -- some_folder
|     | -- project_1
|     | -- project_2
|     ...files relating to both projects...
```

Starting a fresh Next.js project should not be coming up with any errors, don't know what am I doing wrong.

This is my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "next"
}
```

And this is the `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

To tell exactly what type of solutions I already tried:

- Adding `next/babel` in the `.eslintrc.json`
- installing `babel-eslint` but nothing helped!

Comment: Did you get any further on this? I get the same error in vscode with a turborepo setup, using pnpm. I checked and my project has the next/bable folder inside the project's node-modules (i.e. the one you call project_1. Thanks

Comment: @Magnus I'm also using turborepo and got the same error. Have you fixed it?

Comment: No solution guys, I added next/babel in my eslint config but it seems to stop detecting other errors too

Comment: @dzcpy I am not experiencing the problem anymore, but do not remember what I did. Have you tried starting from one of the turborepo examples? For instance the one with tailwind. I tested it yesterday and it works well. It has eslint already set up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in your `.eslintrc.json` file replace `{"extends": "next" }` with

`{ "extends": ["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals" ] }`

Comment: It does fix the issue on the individual files but weirdly running yarn lint produces an error: "Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from"

Comment: This does not work for me. By adding it, eslint stops working entirely

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding next/babel in the eslintrc.json file

```
{"extends": ["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals"]}
```

another recommendation is to use only "next" like:

```
{"extends": ["next", "next/core-web-vitals"]}
```

try both solutions and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from eslintrc.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71662525/failed-to-load-config-next-babel-to-extend-from-eslintrc-json#answer-75197618)
It's not a babel error, but instead, it has something to do with VSCode's eslint config

Answer (score -1):

instead of this in eslintrc.json
{
"extends": "next"
}
use this
{
"next/babel","next/core-web-vitals",
}
I think this will fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).