# VS-code error "Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions'" but npm start and linting works

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I am developing a REST API backend with express and I need to import some JSON local files, so I used the experimental `assert { type: "json" }` syntax.

ESLint still doesn't support it, the solution is to use `babel` parser for ESLint.

I added as dev dependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.21.8",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions": "^7.20.0"
```

I added in `.eslintconfi.json`:

```
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "babelOptions": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
      ]
    }
  },
```

The linting works just fine but VScode gives me `Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions` error on every file:

[image: error]

Comment: did you run `npm install`?

Comment: @starball yes, packages works correctly, the problem is only vscode

Comment: did you follow the instructions here: https://babeljs.io/docs/editors#visual-studio-code ?

Comment: @starball yes, problem still there :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was opening multiple folders with eslint in the same workspace, both `frontend` and `backend` in my case. Opening only the `backend` the issue disappears.

To open both folders in the same workspace edit workspace settings (`.vscode/settings.json` file), adding:
`{ "eslint.workingDirectories": ["frontend", "backend"] }`

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178254/vscode-eslint-configuration-for-a-two-projects-workspace)