# eslint error showing up in VSCode but not when running "eslint" command in terminal? (Vite, React, TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, vite

Just as the title says, I have this ESLint error (`import/no-unresolved`) showing up for `@` path aliases in VSCode, but not in my terminal. I'm pretty sure I have the correct configurations in `vite.config.ts`, `tsconfig.json`, and `.eslintrc.yml`, so I'm not sure what's going on. Are the versions of ESLint in the terminal vs. VSCode somehow different?

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/hsunami10/pomodoro)

**FYI:** I checked to see if it was a global installation of ESLint, but `npm ls -g` gives:

```
/usr/local/lib
└── npm@10.2.3
```

### Screenshots

[image]

And this is the output I get from running `npx eslint .` AND `npm run lint` in the terminal.

[image]

### Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "pomodoro",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "lint:fix": "npm run --silent lint --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier --check \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx,css,md}\" --config ./.prettierrc.yml",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx,css,md}\" --config ./.prettierrc.yml",
    "format": "npm run --silent prettier:fix && npm run --silent lint:fix",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.10.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.16.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "prettier": "3.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}
```

### vite.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import { resolve } from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // Path aliases for imports (alphabetical order)
      //* IMPORTANT: Mirror changes in tsconfig.json, .eslintrc.yml
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@assets': resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
      '@components': resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      '@routes': resolve(__dirname, './src/routes'),
    },
  },
});
```

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Absolute paths */
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      // Path aliases for imports (alphabetical order)
      //* IMPORTANT: Mirror changes in vite.config.ts, .eslintrc.yml
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["src/routes/*"]
    },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    /* https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/ */
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

### .eslintrc.yml

```yaml
root: true
env:
  browser: true
  es2021: true
  jest: true
extends:
  - eslint:recommended
  - plugin:import/recommended
  - plugin:import/typescript
  - plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended
  - plugin:react/recommended
  - plugin:react/jsx-runtime # After React v17+, no need to import React from 'react' everywhere.
  - plugin:react-hooks/recommended
  - prettier # eslint-config-prettier (put it last to override other configs)
ignorePatterns:
  - dist
  - node_modules

parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
parserOptions:
  ecmaFeatures:
    jsx: true
  ecmaVersion: latest
  sourceType: module
plugins:
  - '@typescript-eslint'
  - react
  - react-refresh

settings:
  # Fix the "Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings" message.
  react:
    version: detect

  # import/extensions:
  #   - .ts
  #   - .tsx
  import/parsers:
    '@typescript-eslint/parser':
      - .ts
      - .tsx
  # Absolute paths
  import/resolver: # eslint-import-resolver-***
    # https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1485#issuecomment-535351922
    typescript: {}
    alias:
      extensions:
        - .ts
        - .tsx
      map:
        # Path aliases for imports (alphabetical order)
        #* Mirror changes in vite.config.ts, tsconfig.json
        - ['@', './src']
        - ['@assets', './src/assets']
        - ['@components', './src/components']
        - ['@routes', './src/routes']
```

### VSCode settings.json

```json
{
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[shellscript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "foxundermoon.shell-format",
    "files.eol": "\n"
  },
  "[ignore]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "foxundermoon.shell-format"
  },
  "[gitignore]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "foxundermoon.shell-format"
  },
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode ESlint server is having trouble in finding the ESLint config file.

Pay attention to the project structure, by default ESlint VSCode extension will look for the ESlint config file relative to working directory.

- If you open the `frontend` folder with VSCode instead of the project `pomodoro` folder than it will work like a charm.
- If you want to use in this way, opening the pomodoro folder, than you can configure the `Working Directories ESlint Setting`, like suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178254/vscode-eslint-configuration-for-a-two-projects-workspace).

  Use this in the VSCode ESLint Extension Settings

  ```
  {
     "eslint.workingDirectories": ["frontend"]
  }
  ```